# Insert a subquery count from a main SQL query

Tags: php, sql

I have to list some customers orders in my ecommerce back-office.

I work on the php orders page

This query works fine. Take around 4 secs. :

```
 select o.orders_id, o.customers_email_address, o.transaction_id,
 o.customers_name, o.payment_method, o.date_purchased, o.last_modified,
 o.currency, o.currency_value, s.orders_status_name, ot.text as
 order_total
from TABLE_ORDERS  o left join TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL ot on
 (o.orders_id = ot.orders_id), TABLE_ORDERS_STATUS s
 where o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id
and ot.class = 'ot_total'
order by o.orders_id DESC
```

I try now to add the total number of orders for each customer listed.

This standalone query works fine too  :

```
select count(o.orders_id) as total_ord
from TABLE_ORDERS o
where o.customers_email_address = '" . $orders['customers_email_address'] . "'
```

With $orders['customers_email_address'] extracted from the previous query.

Now the page took 9 to 10 secondes to list customers orders and number of orders per customer.

Is there a way to merge to main query and the subquery count to reduce request time ? 
I tried some left join with no success.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Start by fixing the `JOIN`s. The `,` is archaic and the `WHERE` clause turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

You can try calculating the total number of orders using a window function:

```
select o.orders_id, o.customers_email_address, 
       o.transaction_id,
       o.customers_name, o.payment_method, 
       o.date_purchased, o.last_modified,
       o.currency, o.currency_value, s.orders_status_name, 
       ot.text as order_total,
       o.total_ord
from (select o.*,
             count(*) over (partition by o. customers_email_address) as total_ord
      from table_orders  o
     ) o join
     table_orders_total ot
     on o.orders_id = ot.orders_id join
     table_orders_status s
     on o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id
where ot.class = 'ot_total'
order by o.orders_id desc
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I have an error : '
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by o.customers_email_address) as total_ord from table_orders o) o joi' at line 1

select count(*) as total from (select o.*, count(*) over (partition by o.customers_email_address) as total_ord from table_orders o) o join table_orders_total ot on o.orders_id = ot.orders_id join table_orders_status s on o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id where ot.class = 'ot_total''
I've carefully check the syntax

Comment: , After digging more : MySql doesn't support window Function.

Comment: @SebastienR. . . . Of course it does.  You are just using an older version.

Comment: ok. Sorry not to have mentioned that. Many thanks for your help Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

After digging more : MySql doest support window Function.

So with the help of Gordon Linoff I re-wrote the query that works with a count subquery.

The cons : 14 seconds ! instead of 9 seconds. Too bad, I'll have to use the 2 queries like before.

Anyway I've learn't something.

Working but too long query :

```
   select o.orders_id, o.customers_email_address, 
       o.transaction_id, o.customers_name, o.payment_method, 
       o.date_purchased, o.last_modified,
o.currency, o.currency_value, s.orders_status_name, 
       ot.text as order_total,
  (select count(orders_id) FROM TABLE_ORDERS WHERE customers_email_address = o.customers_email_address) as total_ord
      from table_orders o join
     table_orders_total ot
     on o.orders_id = ot.orders_id join
     table_orders_status s
     on o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id
where ot.class = 'ot_total'
order by o.orders_id desc
```